# Persistently enabling software collections

Tags: centos, rhel, scl

In my CentOS6 server,  I use software collections which goes to the `/opt` directory on install, with the following format.

```
/opt/repository_name/collection_name
# eg /opt/remi/php56,/opt/rh/python27 etc
```

As this [[ article ]](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/527703) suggests, to persistently enable collections I add scripts to `/etc/profile.d` in the following format:

```
#!/bin/bash
source scl_source enable collection_name
```

My question is whether the collections themselves are grouped by repositories - in the example above one went to `rh` folder and the other went to `remi` -  from where they came from would anyway affect the behavior of such scripts i put in`/etc/profile.d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 
[RedHat Packaging Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/Packaging_Guide/sect-The_Software_Collection_Root_Directory.html)
 advises that packages should use the layout */opt/provider/prefix-application-version/* where the prefix consists of the provider name, eg `myorganization-ruby193`.  It [notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/Packaging_Guide/sect-The_Software_Collections_Prefix.html) that

> Software Collections which were first shipped with Red Hat Software Collections 1.x, they do not specify the provider's name in their prefixes. Newer Software Collections added in Red Hat Software Collections 2.0 and later use rh as the provider's name. For example: `rh-ruby22`

So the collections are grouped by provider, and `sci` will only have problems if 2 providers provide the same collection and version without using their name as prefix to disambiguate.